# Access system icons on Tizen wareable

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I am trying to show Tik mark/Ok sign on a button. I saw there's style function [here](https://github.com/Samsung/tizen-docs/blob/master/docs/application/native/guides/ui/efl/mobile/component-button.md) and changed 
style but did not get anything on button.

tried with this code:

```
/* Add a button and set a style */
button = elm_button_add(box);
elm_object_style_set(button, "circle"); // setting style here and omitting below icon codes to test.

/* Set a text to the button */
elm_object_text_set(button, "Home");

/* Add an icon and set it as a content */
icon = elm_icon_add(button);
elm_icon_standard_set(icon, "home");
elm_object_part_content_set(button, "icon", icon);

evas_object_show(button);
elm_box_pack_end(box, button);
```

I do not get any icon on button while testing with different styles. Also no home icon appeared with this code on wearable.

How can get system icons on button?

Answer (score 1):

That guide is a mobile guide.
"circle" style look is different.
In tizen 5.5 wearable. "circle" style of the button is a button that can only use icons with transparent bg.
From what I've found, standard icon is not supported in tizen wearable.
I recommend using elm_image with custom image file.

Sorry for not helping.